# Redirect deleted directory/file to a new location using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, codeigniter-url, cloaking

How can I modify my .htaccess to direct users attempting to view old page URLs on our website to the new version? For example:

Old non-functioning URL: `www.mysite.com/128`

New URL: `www.mysite.com/this-is-the-new-location/321`

I would like `www.mysite.com/128` to show the new page content.

Comment: you want to redirect to the page or show the content of `this-is-the-new-location/321` with the `128` url?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? Do you have a a piece of code already tried?

Comment: Thanks guy, I did Google it and have come up with `Redirect /128 http://www.mysite.com/this-is-the-new-location/321` which is a simple redirect. I would prefer to cloak the URL and show the content of the new page on the old URL so as to not confuse the old users.

Comment: googling it found also a tool to do it http://www.htaccessredirect.net/index.php :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be it

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 www.mysite.com/128 www.mysite.com/this-is-the-new-location/321

//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 www.mysite.com/128(.*) www.mysite.com/this-is-the-new-location/321/$1
```